# inserting date time into table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am inserting few values including time into table. But here all other attr are being stored except datatime.

query:

```
$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
$insertQuery2 = "INSERT INTO userpost(`userid`, `url`, `desc`, `preview`, `img_url`, `title` ,`hash`,`time`) 
VALUES     ('".$user_id."','".$url."','".$content."','".$Preview."','".$logo."','".$title_display."','".$hash."','".$rate."','".$date."')";
```

table:

```
mysql> desc userpost;
+---------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| userid  | varchar(40)   | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| url     | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| desc    | varchar(2048) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| preview | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| img_url | varchar(128)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| title   | varchar(128)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| hash    | varchar(128)  | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| rate    | varchar(16)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| time    | varchar(64)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: you can use NOW() function directly to save the date in the date field, instead of taking it in a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Column count doesn't  match,  `,'".$rate."'` you are added $rate value in insert query

```
 $insertQuery2 = "INSERT INTO userpost(`userid`, `url`, `desc`, `preview`, `img_url`, `title` ,`hash`,`time`)
VALUES     ('".$user_id."','".$url."','".$content."','".$Preview."','".$logo."','".$title_display."','".$hash."','".$date."')";
```

Added rate column and its value ,

```
   $insertQuery2 = "INSERT INTO userpost(`userid`, `url`, `desc`, `preview`, `img_url`, `title` ,`hash`,`rate`,`time`)
VALUES     ('".$user_id."','".$url."','".$content."','".$Preview."','".$logo."','".$title_display."','".$hash."','".$rate."','".$date."')";
```